# How to make an object globally available to other classes

Tags: java, oop

In my main method, I first create an object X

Later in the same main method, I create several more objects (A, B, and C) that all need to be aware of object X.  Right now, I pass a reference to object X into the constructor of classes A, B, and C.

This works fine, but I was wondering if, in the spirit of OOP, there is a better way to make object X globally available to other classes?

Comment: The clean way to deal with dependencies is to use dependency injection. That's what you're doing, manually. But a DI framework could do it for you.

Comment: Not really, no. You might consider a [DI Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) - this would essentially do what you're doing for you.

Comment: they might need to be aware of some property of x not complete object x , right ??

Comment: @Hussain how does that change the question? Replace `X` with `Y` where `Y` is a property of `X` and you have exactly the same problem.

Comment: if its a property , it can be set by some global final variable , which x which set , but other objects will only read

Comment: @Hussain and why can't `X` be set as a global variable in exactly the same way?

Comment: The questions haven't addressed singletons. Is there ever any reason to have more than one instance of X?

Comment: yeah that too , same thing

Comment: Thanks for all the replies so far :-).  Looking into DI...

Comment: Down the rabbit hole of DI I wnet.  I found the Wikipedia article to be the most helpful (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and it confirmed I'm on the right path.  Especially helpful was the discussion of when to use what DI (Constructor, Setter, Interface).  Thanks to all again for the (almost instant) replies :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the 'spirit of OOP' that makes it better to make an object globally available, rather than to the objects that need it. In fact the spirit of Good Programming expects that you will make objects available only to those that need them. If you make an object globally available you cannot guarantee that at any time any other object will modify it. Even if it is unmodifiable you have less control over what the object is used for, and thus will have to make tighter controls on maintenence.

The right thing to do in this case is exactly what you are doing. Pass references to the object explicitly, ideally in their constructors. If the object is available when they are constructed then it makes complete sense to do it.

If you find in some other circumstances that you truly need to make a class available globally, and you cannot possibly find a way around it, then a Singleton is probably the best way. But do that absolutely only if there is no other way.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense to me :-)  My problem is that I know just enough OOP to be dangerous, but do not have a good grasp of the big picture yet to allow me to decide whether what I'm doing follows OOP principles.  Looks like I got this right though.